# how to open a html gwt page within another by clicking a button

Tags: gwt

I have a DockLayoutPanel in my GWT, I have defined the North, South and West as the folloing

```
dockLayoutPanel.addNorth(new HTML("PLACE HOLDER FOR HEADER"), 8);
dockLayoutPanel.addSouth(new HTML("PLACE HOLDER FOR FOTTER"), 5);
dockLayoutPanel.addWest(scrollPanel, 50);----scrollPanel is basically a flextable with buttons.
```

Basically what I want to achieve is when the user clicks on the button that is in the `flextable`, it has to open an another HTML gwt page within the same page towards the right side of the button.(i.e within the same page and in the center of the `dockLayoutPanel`).

Can someone please help me with this.
First thing is how to embed HTML gwt page within another
and Second is how to open it with click of the button within the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood your problem, you want to embed a HTML page inside an GWT application with the help of a button. This is one of the possible solutions.

- First create an iFrame using [Frame](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Frame.html) class of GWT.
- Next add a click handler for the button
- In the onClick method of the click handler populate the created iFrame with the required URL (path of your HTML page).

IFrame has many other potential uses. You can use it to display data which is accessed from some remote server even which is not  related to Gwt or Java. Think IFrame as a photo frame. You can either put a color photo or a black and white photo or a paper it doesn't matter. IFrame acts as portal for you to display anything.

Answer (score 0):

As described here: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels

```
  Button b = new Button("Click Me");
    b.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
      public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // handle the click event
        dockLayoutPanel.add(<Add the page here>)
    }   });
```

Everything happens direktly on the same page with an Ajay request.

You should read following tutorial to understand the mvp-pattern, that helps a lot.
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture