# Running Browser specific technologies with GWT

Tags: gwt, cross-browser

I don't know whether my title is correct but I have the following problem.

I am new to GWT and trying to explore various options before I port our thick client to thin client using GWT.

Say we have a browser specific implementation, say some application is developed using ASP.NET and data is in some windows server and runs only on IE. Now how to project the output of this data in my GWT application. Since GWT have cross-browser support, how to project my data in GWT which is specific to IE. The part of data that which is browser specific is pretty huge and to port it to GWT might take a long time. Is there any intermediate solution for this?

Comment: Can you provide a little more clarity in question whether you intend to support other browsers or just trying to wrap/embed existing aspx application in GWT frame.

Comment: In the long run, we will try to convert the existing aspx app to GWT, but since it is a heavy project we want an intermediate solution while in the mean time we figure out how to carry over the process to converting it into GWT app. For that GWT frame might be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an intermediate solution to your question which I think should work.

So you already have working application which is browser specific and hosted on some server.
You can use the concept of [IFrame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) here.

GWT provides you to implement IFrame with the help of [Frame](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Frame.html) class.

You can run your application in the server it is currently running and provide its URL to IFrame which you created. This make sure the output of your application is rendered in your GWT application without much effort. Have a look at this answer of mine to a questin which had similar query

[how to open a html gwt page within another by clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488057/how-to-open-a-html-gwt-page-within-another-by-clicking-a-button/13493593#13493593)

Comment: I din't knew I could use IFrame in GWT. I will give it a try. Thanks